# <zipfileset> vs. <fileset> in ant

Tags: ant

The ant build tool provides two different tasks `<fileset/>` and `<zipfileset/>`.
According to the documentation `<zipfileset/>` allows us to extract files from a .zip file 
if we use `src` attribute.

My question is **if we are using `dir` attribute to select files then what is the difference between the two,  `<zipfileset/>` and `<fileset/>`.**

e.g.

```
                <zipfileset dir="conf/Gateway>
                <include name="jndi.properties" />
                </zipfileset>

                                 and

                <fileset dir="conf/Gateway>
                <include name="jndi.properties" />
                </fileset>
```

Comment: did you run it? could you post a complete target?

Comment: @Jayan both scripts work.see the link i posted in the comments of your answer

Answer (score 4):

One useful difference between the two tasks if you're building an archive (a ZIP or WAR or JAR for example) is that a `zipfileset` has a `prefix` attribute you can use to relocate the given files at a different folder in the archive.  For example, if the following is included in a bigger set of `fileset` and `zipfileset` elements:

```
<zipfileset dir="conf/Gateway" prefix="properties">
    <include name="jndi.properties" />
</zipfileset>
```

then the file `conf/Gateway/jndi.properties` will actually be included in the output as `conf/Gateway/properties/jndi.properties`.  You can achieve the same end in other ways, but this is occasionally useful.

Otherwise, just use the task that seems most appropriate for the task at hand.